# Preferred MySQL tools

Tags: mysql

Hi what are the preferred mysql tools with professional developers.  I am a recent computing graduate and have used the query browser and administrator from mysql throughout university and i have found them to be very useful.

I start a new job in a couple of weeks though as a web developer and was wondering whether they would be exepcting me to use the command line or some other mysql tools.

What do the professional developers generally use for interacting with mysql databses i.e. creating new schemas, tables etc.

Comment: Should be community wiki?  If the question doesn't already exist...

Answer (score 3):

[This is the tool to generate MySQL queries](http://www.knowledgewalls.com/mysqlcreatedatabase). There you can find MySQL generator for different commands, like drop table, create table, rename database, create database etc.

Answer (score 2):

[mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqladmin.html) should be sufficient for most of the tasks if not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) is fantastic. It might work on Linux through Wine, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Another Windows tool: [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/go/?go=dbw), works on Linux via Wine and supports other database systems as well.

Answer (score 2):

I occasionally use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), as it can help speed up schema design (and the price is right).  A cursory knowledge of [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is useful as it is often the admin tool of choice on web hosting servers. Most of the time, however, I just use the command line interface from Linux.

Understanding what goes on beneath the GUI is a very useful (dare I say essential) skill to have.  Just look here on SO, where you'll find a vast number of SQL scripts that would be difficult to explain or implement if a GUI had to be factored in.

The CLI is available almost everywhere. If you ever have to work on a computer other than your own, be it on site or in your office, you can be fairly certain that CLI access will be available. The same cannot be said for your GUI of choice.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) is what I turned to after *trying* to use HeidiSQL. I liked HeidiSQL but I loved SQLyog. There is a free version somewhere.

Comment: I use SQLyog community edition on ubuntu, with Wine. It's the best, IMO, here's the link to the project: http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/ .

Comment: I agree - SQLyog is my preferred both on ubuntu and windows. phpmyadmin is useful too because almost always available.

Answer (score 1):

Probably

- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)
- [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[DB Forge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/)

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac for development I use [Querious](http://www.araelium.com/querious/). The application is very well written and supports connecting to local and remote databases.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the tools you point out are good, and they would probably expect you to have some familiarity with them. Usually I will use a tool such as Query Browser or pgAdmin (for PostGreSQL) to run simple queries.

Once you have more experience you might find the command-line tools helpful as well. It's only going to help you by learning them.

Answer (score 0):

For most big companies, you usually use **Microsoft Visio** to develop and plot the database as well as the web layout.