# GUI tools for mysql 5.0

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2005, ssms

Is their any GUI-interface for MySQL, like Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Server Management Studio provides? Because basically I am operating MySQL with command prompt interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql query browser:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Comment: MySQL Query Browser is EOL - better to use Workbench now.

Answer (score 5):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) should be enough for simple purposes. If not, you can use the [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) package or search for commercial tools if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

i used [SQLYOG](http://www.webyog.com/en/index.php), 
you can download the Community edition (free) from :

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There used to be MySQL Administrator and MySQL Query Browser, but those are not supported anymore.

#### Clientside

- MySQL AB recommends to use the new [MySQL Workbench (GUI Tool)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)
- TOAD and MySQLYog are pretty popular too.

#### Serverside

- PHPMyAdmin is pretty friendly for inexperiences users, but more experiences users don't always like it.

Answer (score 2):

Also useful,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126791/best-mysql-server-monitoring-tool

[Best MySQL performance tuning tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362223/best-mysql-performance-tuning-tool)

[Preferred MySQL tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207873/preferred-mysql-tools)

searching stackoverflow for more results.

Answer (score 1):

I like Navicat or MySQL GUI tools

Answer (score 1):

I have tried 3 different MySQL GUI clients.

- [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
- [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com)
- [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) ([Free community edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list))

IMO, HeidiSQL has a nicer GUI and more useful features than the other two.

In HeidiSQL you can use Ctrl+Space for auto-complete (just like Eclipse IDE). For example, you can start typing

```
SELECT * FROM st
```

then Ctrl+Space and it will open a pop-up displaying all table names in the selected DB that start with 'st' from which you can select the table.

You can also use table aliases and use auto-complete for column names. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM students s WHERE s.
```

and then type Ctrl+Space and it will list all the columns in the 'students' table. I could not find this auto-complete feature in MySQL workbench and SQLyog community edition.

Another cool HeidiSQL (and SQLyog) feature is you can browse the rows in a table if you click on the "data" tab. Otherwise you would have to type

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename>
```

and if the table is large and you forget to add LIMIT clause, this may take long to run. HeidiSQL automatically limits the number of rows to 1000. Also, when browsing data, you can add filters (equivalent of WHERE clause) and sort options (equivalent of ORDER BY clause).

The one feature that HeidiSQL does not have which SQLyog has is automatic SQL keyword upper-casing as you type your SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I use toad http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql and the older mysql gui tools http://download.softagency.net/mysql/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-gui-tools-5.0-r17-win32.msi and sometimes the newer mysql workbench http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

SQLyog enterprise edition can be used for using mysql but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

I think dbForge Studio for MySQL is most like SQL Server Management Studio: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/